# Ubuntu freezes before or after logging but no in recovery mode

Tags: boot, 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and the first day it worked fine then the second day after a few seconds of boot Ubuntu freezes but when I got to grub and go recovery mode and normal boot it works fine but games are unplayable so does someone knows how to fix this please?

Comment: Please don't change the question's title to include `[SOLVED]` when your problem is solved. Instead, accept one of the given answers or write a self-answer and accept that. It is perfectly OK and encouraged to [answer your very own question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Oops i can only choose an corect answere in 21 hours...

Comment: Yes that's a limitation. You can accept it tomorrow then. I think if you write a question and an answer in one go and post them together, then you can accept it immediately, but I'm not sure. But thank you for adding your answer. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I already solved the problem. The problem was pretty simple to solve actually. If anyone has that problem here is a tutorial:

On `grub` go to advanced options Ubuntu recovery then when you are on the recovery menu press `boot normally`. It will boot in Ubuntu recovery mode

Open a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repostitory ppa:teejee2008/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Now go to the applications, open the one called `ukuu`, select the latest kernel, press download, wait for it to download, and then restart the computer and boot ubuntu normally. DONE!

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your problem. Does Ubuntu still freezes or is fine now. Make sure that the disk are mount it by your system. Are the games in a different partition?

Comment: Ubuntu freezes after 2s it is boot but it doesnt freeze in recovery mode and no the games are not in different partitons by the way my pc is a lenovo ideapad 320s

Answer (score 0):

solutions that may work

- in grub, select ubuntu and press e, it will open a text editor, search for `quiet splash` and make it `quiet splash acpi=force`
  Press ctrl X to boot. Fixed
  Do it every reboot or edit grub and add it, don't forget to sudo update grub after editing.
- Disable secure boot from bios

Comment: Should i keep $vt_handoff or do i remove that because i wrote splash acpi=force but didnt remove $vt_handoff and it didnt work and yes i disabled secure boot

Comment: And my computer is a lenovo 320s if that can help

Comment: Add acpi=force in the quotes like "quiet splash acpi=force" , don't touch any other thing

Comment: Already solved it i just updated the kernel